# UploadFile Control loses it's data on PostBacks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

What's wrong! .. seems like it's a common issue .. and even if I try to persist it's value I can only keep it in anywhere like a hiddenfield but looks like there's no property that saves the whole location of the file on the local machine and even if I got it, I can't assign the value back to the FileUpload because all of it's properties are ReadOnly!

Any simple solutions please !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is by design - file upload is readonly because otherwise it would be a huge security risk... see http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#file-select

depending on what functionality you are trying to implement there could be other possible solutions... please elaborate.

Comment: I see what you mean, it's definitely risky .. but if it's risk then why don't microsoft save us the headache and make the UploadFile save it's data through PostBacks! .. I've been having the same issue with the repeater but this is solvable by controlling the time of binding!

Comment: "Here's an example: Div1: Personal Info Div2: Skils N.B I Navigate through the 2 divs through 2 buttons that shows the one that I need and hides the other divs. Now both divs contain controls to enter some related data, I might just enter my name in the first divs and then go to the second divs add a skill, and I need to go back to the first divs to continue my personal info .. this switching will happen a lot, so I need to keep the info persistent in the controls so If I switch from a div to another I don't want to lose the data that I entered first"

Comment: that works but NOT for fileupload... perhaps you should put your fileupload on the last step of the process (right before the user submits) or on a div that's always visible... otherwise you will have to take the uploaded file when it first arrives and show the file name in some div to the user with a button/link to remove it again

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if you can set that field programatically; what would stop a malicious developer from populating that field and accessing the user's files?

short answer is that every postback will require the user to select the file again for upload.    If the postback occurs, it means the file is bad, so the user should be selecting another file anyway.

If the postback occurs because the user entered incorrect metadata for the file, while the file itself is fine, then you can just cache the file name and display it for the user again.  Just put a fake, read-only textbox on top of the actual file upload textbox and display the file name back to the user.  The file should have already been uploaded to the web server so no upload is necessary (i.e. the real file upload textbox can remain blank)

Comment: You're are right about the security thing .. but the PostBack that happen in my page is totally not related to the FileUpload! :S .. check my comments above on Yahia's Answer please.